# Problems setting up a secure WSS connection for Sipml5

Tags: linux, ssl, asterisk, webrtc

I have problems with setting up a webrts connection with sipml5 through an asterisk. When I check the status of https through the asterisk console, I get a response that it is up and running. But when I try to connect to sipml5 in the browser, I get the error WebSocket connection to 'wss://ipserv:8089/ws' failed:. in the asterisk console when I try to connect I get 3 errors:
[Aug 18 12:08:17] ERROR[7078]: iostream.c:647 ast_iostream_start_tls: Problem setting up ssl connection: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1), Internal SSL error
[Aug 18 12:08:17] ERROR[7078]: tcptls.c:179 handle_tcptls_connection: Unable to set up ssl connection with peer 'myip:64433'
[Aug 18 12:08:17] ERROR[7078]: iostream.c:552 ast_iostream_close: SSL_shutdown() failed: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1), Internal SSL error

how to solve this error? I just started learning these technologies. any support would mean a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

You should use a network sniffing tool like tcpdump and/or wireshark to check the TLS handshake's version (TLSv1.0, 1.1, 1.2 or 1.3) and the cipher suites. Probably the there's an incompatibility or no matching cipher.